# android studio navigate back shortcut not working in windows

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Has anyone (who is using windows) had this problem that navigate back shortcut in Android Studio is not working? The shortcut key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> Arrow is not working, which, I guess, is because of conflicting with some graphic card's shortcut. Is there a way to get rid of that?

I tried to disable the key combination in the graphic card setting, but still not working. It's intel graphic card, btw.

Another fact is that after I remove the combination in Android studio keymap, the adding shortcut setting does not recognized the key combination.

Comment: Happens the same with me, but I'm on Linux (ubuntu-based distro)! And also, re-adding the shortcut key with `"Alt+Ctrl+Left/Right Arrow"` is not even recognized, too. Ended up setting the Eclipse-way of doing it..

Comment: yea, i also changed it to "alt+left/right arrow" now..

Comment: I had the same problem in Ubuntu. In turns out that the default Ubuntu desktop uses Ctrl+Alt+arrows as a shortcut to change workspace. They intercept these shortcuts before Android Studio but as the default install only has a single workspace, it seems like they do not work.

Go in System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Navigation and delete the matching shortcuts (using backspace)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Navigation:

> **Control Pane**l[Select large icon]> **Find Intel graphics option** > **Open
>   setting screen**

Just try to customize new hotkeys in Intel Graphics panel,
does not metter - disable or enable this hot keys
[image]

Answer (score 14):

Just disable the hot keys from the graphics option -> Hot Keys -> Disable in the tray.
Worked for me.

**Edit:** Added screenshot 
[image]

Comment: didn't work for me.  had to actually remap the hot keys in the intel settings, even though i disabled them.

Comment: Awesome! worked for me - much easier than reassigning the shortcut keys

Answer (score 2):

Actually I had to reasign this hot keys for something other, then disable

Comment: Yeah even i had to reassign the hot keys and then disabling them worked.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For intel graphics, right-click in desktop and choose `Graphics Properties` (or go Control panel and Intel graphic app) then choose to `Option and support` tab then hotkey manager and uncheck `Hot key` in top, or change keys in below.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar for me:

Intel Graphics Command Center -> System -> HotKeys -> Enable System HotKeys: Off

Please note, that if it is already turned off, turn it on and off again. I'm not kidding. I had to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10, just disable the hotkeys of Graphics

> 1. Go to Desktop.
> 2. Right-click anywhere on the desktop screen.
> 3. Select "Graphics Options" -> "Hot Keys" -> "Disable"

[image: Disbale Hot Keys of Graphics]

Answer (score 0):

### Solution For Ubuntu

Not all navigation keyboard shortcuts are listed in Settings GUI therefore you won't be able to unbind <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> from there.[image]

1. Verify that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> are effectively bound to "Switch to workspace left/right":

   `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left`
   `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right`
2. Unbind the shortcuts:

   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"`

   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "[]"`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for any issue related to keys is to Restore Default Copy.

To restore go to **File -> Settings -> Keymap -> Select Windows/Default copy** *(If you are using default Keymap or select your current keymap)* from drop-down then click on the small settings button and select **Restore Default Copy** in the option.

[image]